# How do i clear the canvas for another animation?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Was wondering if any of you could help me

I've got to create an advert and want to have text flying in from the right.

So far I've managed to do it, but cannot clear the canvas for reanimation.

Here's my code so far:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="200">Your browser doesn't support the canvas. <br/> I appologise for any inconvenience. 

</canvas>

<script type = "text/javascript">

    //Set up the canvas
    var the_canvas_element = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var the_canvas = the_canvas_element.getContext("2d");

    //Start Variables
    var x = 800;

    //Start animation timing
    var int = setInterval(draw,10);

    var ljmulogo = new Image ();
    {
        ljmulogo.src = 'C:\Users\Chad\Documents\My Web Sites\CWK 2\Part A\Images\ljmu_logo.png'
        setInterval (draw,100)
    }

    function draw()
    {
        //Clear canvas
        the_canvas.clearRect(0,0,800,200);

        //Draw text
        the_canvas.fillStyle = "#000000";
        the_canvas.font = "24pt arial";
        the_canvas.fillText("Welcome to:",x,30);

        the_canvas.fillStyle = "#000000";
        the_canvas.font = "bold 24pt arial";
        the_canvas.fillText("Liverpool John Moores University",x,70);

        the_canvas.fillStyle = "#000000";
        the_canvas.font = "32pt arial";
        the_canvas.fillText("Computer Forensics",x,150);


        //Check if at the end
        if (x<=20)
        {
            //End animation
            int = clearInterval(int);
        }
        else
        {
            //bring text in further
            x = x -2;
        }

    }


</script>
```

Thanks a lot for any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on here, it doesn't look valid:

```
var ljmulogo = new Image ();
{
    ljmulogo.src = 'C:\Users\Chad\Documents\My Web Sites\CWK 2\Part A\Images\ljmu_logo.png'
    setInterval (draw,100)
}
```

To create a new image, try this:

```
//This code outside the draw loop
var ljmulogo = new Image();
ljmulogo.src = 'ljmu_logo.png';

//This code inside the draw loop
ctx.drawImage(ljmulogo, 0, 0);
```

(and remove the setInterval (draw,100) as you already have a setInterval + that 100 value is pretty high).